# How to display a face in world tracking

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm playing around with the new `ARKit3` and especially with the simultaneously world and face tracking.

I couldn't find a good tutorial or example.

I don't get how to start.

My goal would be, I could display a face in the world tracking that is showing my facial expressions(that are recorded from the front camera).

Really hoping someone can help me.

```
//That's my setup for the configuration
private func setupFaceTracking() {

    guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return }
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    configuration.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
    arView.session.run(configuration, options: [])
}
```

[As a reference, this is what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjEI4.png)

Answer (score 2):

You're correct so far. You need to set up an `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` with `userFaceTrackingEnabled`, you'll likely want to also have some kind of plane detection to anchor any face modified node into the scene as well. If you're using the `ARKit` Xcode template you can say something like:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Create a session configuration
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]

    // Run the view's session
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}
```

To get the face mesh you should use `ARSCNFaceGeometry` which can be instantiated using the metal device of your `ARSCNView` and stored as a property on your view controller. For example:

```
lazy var faceGeometry: ARSCNFaceGeometry = {
    let device = sceneView.device!
    let maskGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: device)!
    maskGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    return maskGeometry
}()
```

Now it's a matter of getting the face geometry into the scene and responding to changes in the face.

To get the geometry in the scene I would recommend using a tap gesture that will place the node on the tapped plane. For example:

```
lazy var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = {
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)))
    return gesture
}()
```

Add it to your view in `viewDidLoad` like `sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)`. Then:

```
@objc func didTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
    let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)

    guard let hitTestResult = hitTestResults.first, hitTestResult.anchor is ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
    // create anchor and add to session and wait for callback
    let newAnchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTestResult.worldTransform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: newAnchor)
}
```

This will add an `ARAnchor` at the tapped position. With the anchor added `nodeForAnchor` will be called and we can vend a node that contains our face geometry.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    // Make sure it's not an `ARPlaneAnchor`
    guard !(anchor is ARPlaneAnchor) else { return SCNNode() }

    // create empty node
    let node = SCNNode()

    // Add the stored face geometry as the node's geometry
    node.geometry = faceGeometry

    // Move node up to just above plane
    node.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.15, 0.0)

    // Create light so full topology is visible
    // You could also just set `sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true` to not have to deal with lighting
    let omni = SCNLight()
    omni.type = .omni
    omni.intensity = 3000
    omni.color = UIColor.white
    let omniNode = SCNNode()
    omniNode.light = omni
    omniNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 0.5)

    // Create node to contain face and light
    let parentNode = SCNNode()
    parentNode.addChildNode(node)
    parentNode.addChildNode(omniNode)

    // Return parent node
    return parentNode
}
```

Now we can get the face mask into the scene, it is only a matter of responding to updates. For that we use `didUpdateNode`.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    // If `ARFaceAnchor` update geometry
    if let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor {
        faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
    } 
    // If `ARPlaneAnchor` update plane geometry and color plane
    else if let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor,
        let device = sceneView.device {
        let plane = ARSCNPlaneGeometry(device: device)
        plane?.update(from: anchor.geometry)
        node.geometry = plane
        // For debug, add a color to planes
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    }
}
```

If you do all of that you should get something like:

[image]

You'll want to make sure that device has a clear view of your face. If mask stops responding or node doesn't appear on tap try to hold device in a different position, typically either closer or further from your face.

Comment: I came up with a pretty similar solution, thanks for your effort! I really appreciate it, that's exactly what I was looking for!